# Why do I have the error "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token"

Tags: java, syntax

I am trying to make a game that will generate random numbers and the user will have to guess it.

```
package numberguess;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NumberGuess {

    public void program() {
        int guess1,nmbr;
        Random rand = new Random();
        nmbr = rand.nextInt(100);

        while(true){
            guess1 = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a # 1-100"));
        }

        if(guess1 < nmbr); {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "numerber is too small");
            guess1++;
        }
        else if (guess1 > nmbr) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "number is too big");
            guess1++;
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations you guessed correctly:" + nmbr);
            guess1++;
            break;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
            NumberGuess prog = new NumberGuess();
            prog.program();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code.  We're not psychic!  (Though, if I had to guess, I'd say that you've got an incorrect "else" somewhere.)

Comment: What do you mean? Your question's title have to be `TITLE`... and then you have provide more infomation about your question include your previous attempt and part of your code... please `edit` your question...

Comment: sorry, I put the code up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
    if(guess1 < nmbr); {
```

the `;` ends the `if` block early, causing the following `else` to not match any `if`, leading to a syntax error.  Delete the `;`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray semi-colon after your if(guess1 < nmbr) statement, try removing it.

There's also a problem with an infinite loop with your while(true) statement, you don't need the break in the last else statement, and not entirely sure why you're incrementing guess1 like that.

Good luck with the homework - a journey of a thousand miles starts with one step.

Answer (score 0):

Your last else statement should either have an if condition if guess1 = nmbr after it or remove the second last 'else'.

Also I noticed that if guess1 is too big, you are incrementing it anyway - resulting in the same message over and over again in an infinite loop.